# How to transfer MemoryStream to StreamSource in FopFactory?

Tags: java, apache-fop

I am using the following code in FopFactory running with connected packages IKVM and FOP:

```
using org.apache.fop.tools;
using org.apache.fop.apps;
using org.xml.sax;
using java.io;

public void PDF(MemoryStream inpFile, string pdfFile)
{
OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new java.io.File(pdfFile)));

    try
    {
        FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance();
        Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop("application/pdf", os);
        FOUserAgent foUserAgent = fop.getUserAgent();
        javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory factory = javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        javax.xml.transform.Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer();
        javax.xml.transform.Source src = new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(inpFile);
        javax.xml.transform.Result res = new javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());
        transformer.transform(src, res);
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {                
        throw ex;
    }

    finally
    {
        os.close();
    }
}
```

How to transfer MemoryStream inpFile to javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource in FopFactory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. I used the class [DotNetInputStream](https://github.com/joniles/mpxj/blob/master/src.net/MpxjUtilities/DotNetInputStream.cs) from here. In my code, I added:

```
java.io.InputStream streamFile = new DotNetInputStream(inpFile);
```

And transfer InputStream to StreamSource in FopFactory:

```
javax.xml.transform.Source src = new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(streamFile);
```